# How to validate an attribute only if it exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, conditional-statements, proc

I have a lot of models with many different attributes that are shared between them, and so I have to validate them all and thats where I am having a problem. If I group all attributes that are always used together and put their validations in a separated module, I end up with like 20 modules, which just doesnt seem right... Also I thought about putting attrs validations in only like 2-3 modules grouping them logically, like one module for location attrs, other is for options and etc and additing to all of them the IF condition the following way:

```
validates :city,
presence: true,
length: {minimum: 5},
if: Proc.new {|p| p.respond_to?(:city)}
```

and it looks like it works but repeating this condition to every validation method is just even more wrong than having a bunch of modules, so the question is, how do I do it right?

Edit:
Example:
Imagine you have 3 models: Car, Truck and Bicycle and their attrs are:

> Car -> attr_1, attr_3
>
> Truck -> attr_2, attr_3
>
> Bicycle -> attr_1, attr_2

and so u can put validation of every attr to its module and include it to the clases that have this attribute, so u dont have to repeat it... ( thats where I end up with 20 modules) or u can create only one module with 3 validations like the following:

```
validates :attr_1, length: {minimum: 2}, if: Proc.new {|p| p.respond_to?(:attr_1)}
validates :attr_2, presence: true, if: Proc.new {|p| p.respond_to?(:attr_2)}
validates :attr_3, inclusion: {in: 1..5}, if: Proc.new {|p| p.respond_to?(:attr_3)}
```

which seems to be more ugly ... So I need to find some compromise here ...

Answer (score 1):

Ok... so you have multiple models with a set of related attribute (and validations) on them>

some options are:

1. use a module that is included in each of the models
2. extract the attributes out into a model of its own (with its own attributes and validations) and is polymorphically associated to each of the related models
3. if you are using the latest version of rails, have a look at concerns - which is a better way of doing (1)

if there really are 20 different groups of things... then create 20.
But if groups of these things are always together in every model that uses them... you can put them into one spot together (and use code like Max's suggestion to make it shorter to read)

Comment: it allows the attr to be blank only if it exists on the record, as far as I understand

Comment: hmmm... I guess then I'm not sure exactly what you're getting at above then. Perhaps you could expand on your example?

Comment: oh wait... no I see (sorry, brain fail)... if a model has the attribute :city, then add this validation.

Comment: ah right... in which case, go for Max's suggestion. :)

Comment: yeah, this will help to reduce the amount of code but not very much though since I dont have many similar validations

Comment: by the looks of it, you've got address-like validations. I'd think seriously about creating an address model and pulling all related stuff out to there. The a bike/car/truck etc can have_one :address in a polymorphic relationship and all the validations are at least out of All the models and only in one place

Comment: Thought about it too, but I will end up with many polymorphic tables with the attrs that are  searched which I believe will be slow with a lot of joins

Comment: yep - fair enough. It's always a tradeoff :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember you're just using ruby code here, there's nothing magical going on.  So you can do a loop:

```
[:attr1, :attr2, :attr3].each do |att|
  validates att, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}, if: Proc.new {|p| p.respond_to?(att)}
end
```

Comment: yeah I know about it but I dont think it'll solve the problem coz most of the validations are different

Comment: They're all identical in your question.

Comment: If they're all different then you should just write them in the models as normal.  Your question was about avoiding repetition - now you're saying there's no repetition, which makes your question misleading and kind of pointless.

Comment: I need to avoid only repetition of the if statement, its always the same but with different parameter, I think it can be made better

Comment: With "its always the same but with different parameter", what do you mean by "parameter"?  if it's the attribute then my answer will work.

Comment: I am sorry for misleading, and most validations validate different things but all of them have this "IF" condition, and in every validation it has the same content except the attribute that I pass to  respond_to?

Comment: because it iterates over the attrs and validates the same things for them, presence and length in this case, what if I need to validate uniqueness for attr1 and min length should be 3 instead of 5 for attr2 and etc?

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question.  In your question the three validations are identical apart from the attribute.  I think you should rewrite the question to state what you actually want to do, eg give examples that are different instead of the same.